# Add two borders to input where one has a radius

Tags: css

I'm trying to add two borders to an input text when it's focused, the solution I did is to add a border and a box shadow.

The issue I'm having is that I want the outer border to have a radius of 1px and the inner doesn't have a radius.

How can I achieve that ?

```css
input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #14a7a7;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 3px #83d7d8;
    border-radius: 0;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: there is no radius

Comment: in the current code your `border-radius` is set to 0

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry my question wasn't clear, I have updated it

Comment: @DeniJ. it's because I want the border to not have a radius, but at the same time, I want the outer border to have a radius of 1px

Comment: @RenaudisNotBillGates so the box shadow should have a radius?

Answer (score 1):

Use the box-shadow as the inner border and you can easily add radius

```css
input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px inset #14a7a7;
  border: 3px solid #83d7d8;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px inset #979797;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Or consider an extra wrapper and `:focus-within`

```css
input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #14a7a7;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  outline: 0;
}

label {
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}

label:focus-within {
  border: 3px solid #83d7d8;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="text" /></label>
```